# How to create an arrow in css3?

Tags: css

How to create arrow in css3?
As like this .

[image]

[image]

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BdSP4/1/

Comment: Anything you have tried, its pretty easy?

Comment: see i have made some two samples check it :- http://jsfiddle.net/Ewfkk/28/

Answer (score 7):

[**--- SEE DEMO ----**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/BdSP4/)

```
<div class="triangle-left">
    <div></div>
</div>​

.triangle-left {
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.triangle-left div
{
  border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position:relative;
  top:-9px;
  left:0px;
}​
```

This is a triangle with a white triangle positioned inside, giving the appearance of an arrow. For more information on CSS3 triangles see here:

http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/creating-triangles-in-css/

Comment: @Rohitazad Can you not change your HTML to include this inner div?

Comment: @Curt, Please put some explanations as well.

Comment: @Rohitazad: Then add the second DIV! Development is all about making changes to get the end result that you want

Comment: @Curt check to this link http://jsfiddle.net/BdSP4/1/ and i have post the result images .

Comment: @Rohitazad, This is not a `code for me site` please understand, curt, provided an excellent solution.

Comment: holy smokes, how does that work?

Answer (score 7):

See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/TsPfq/)

HTML

```
<div class="angle"></div>
```

CSS

```
.angle:after { /* Thanks to :after just one div is necessary */
    content: '.';
    border-top: 20px solid #000; /* NW triangle gap */
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000; /* SW triangle gap */
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent; /* W triangle */
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
}
.angle {
    font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 0px; /* Necessary to not screw up the layout */
    border-top: 20px solid transparent; /* NE triangle gap */
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent; /* SE triangle gap */
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 20px solid #000; /* E triangle */
}
```

**Update:** Smaller version

These are 2 overlapping triangles. One is black, one is white.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/TsPfq/2/)

Same HTML, different CSS

```
.angle:after {
    content: '.';
    border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 10px solid white; 
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
}
.angle {
    font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 0px; /* Necessary to not screw up the layout */
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 10px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: why use a cannon to kill a fly?

Comment: @Mikey, Put up some explanations as well.

Comment: @EliranMalka: Because cannons are awesome!

Comment: @Starx: added comments, hope this will help to understand the code some more.

Comment: +1 as I always like to see pseudo elements used to full advantage to keep html markup down. _Though when I looked at your fiddle solution in FF 11, there was a 1px white gap between the front point and the "wings" behind._ I'm sure that can be resolved, but I thought you ought to know.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use CSS 3 - create it with an HTML entity:

```html
<span>&#8249;</span>
```

Comment: This is a cheat answer of Nix's comment

Comment: i posted it before seeing the comment, no false accusations, please :)

Comment: [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/rcmup/2/)

Comment: Rohit azad may not see it because "A character entity reference is an SGML construct that references a character of the document character set," ([see W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/entities.html)), and since he is in Delhi, may be working with a different document character set that does not show the arrow.

Comment: @ScottS - Actually the HTML entity reference would be `&lsaquo;`, the notation in the example uses the unicode character code, and this should be identical for all encodings. Maybe Rohit should first try to display the character as simple text, independend of the styling.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding alternative using CSS3's  `rotate`

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/h8aLR/2/)

CSS

```
.arrow { width: 20px; height: 20px; overflow: hidden; }
.arrow span  {
    display: block;
    border: 4px #000 solid;
    background: #fff;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: -12px;
    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
         M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476, sizingMethod='auto expand');
    zoom: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="arrow"><span></span></div>
```